# How to find a "safe" point for -SS using FFMPEG to avoid breaking A/V sync?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I need to find a way to cut video using -SS without breaking the audio/video sync.

Once in a while it works perfectly fine, but most of the time the audio falls slightly out of synch.  Clearly there is something akin to a keyframe for audio, but I do not know how to find them.

The problem happens when using -SS in conjunction with Any specification for a codec, including -c copy.

For my purposes, I can't lose quality so those are necessary.

```
ffmpeg -i src.mp4 -ss 1:00 -t 30 -c copy result.mp4
```

tends to break the sync.

```
ffmpeg -i src.mpr -ss 1:00 -t 30 result.mp4
```

produces matching a/v but with significant quality loss from using the default compressions.

I need a way to find the times at which a cut will result in matching a/v.

Answer (score 4):

The issue actually has to do with video keyframes.  The audio/video are effectively starting at different times in your MP4 output.

For what it's worth, I've found that using Matroska for the output works fine, as it seemingly supports these differing timestamps better than MP4.

In any case, you might find this discussion helpful:  https://github.com/mifi/lossless-cut/pull/13

Here is the relevant FFmpeg command that will probably work for you.  Please give it a try!

```
ffmpeg -ss 1:00 -i src.mp4 -t 30 -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -c copy result.mp4
```

The key here is `avoid_negative_ts`, which I believe allows for outputting the previous GOP to the file, but setting their timestamps to all happen at zero (up until they shouldn't, of course) so that way they can be used for decoding, allowing you to arbitrarily cut the file without transcoding.

Comment: The Matroska muxer does not allow negative timestamps so what ffmpeg does is write all packets upto the intended cut point with ts 0. Upon playback, the first frame will be displayed and then all frames are dropped till the first non-colliding timestamp is encountered i.e. the cut point. MP4s have edit lists so all frames upto the cut point can be cleanly skipped for presentation. This relies on the consumer being able to process edit lists. Few players don't and I think editors don't either.

Comment: @Gyan Thanks for that clarification.  So, the Matroska muxer is effectively doing `-avoid_negative_ts make_zero` all on its own?

Comment: I haven't checked but I suspect it's the library framework which acts upon the presence/absence of the negative ts flag in the muxer.

Comment: Logged in just to give you upvote. Answer was the solution for me. Before this, audio would get out of sync when using -ss (even using MKV format)